# Save conditional split to variable

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have a data flow in VS2019 that calls a list via REST than does some filtering and returns a single data point (A date formatted as string).

Is it possible to update a variable with that string? And if so how?

I tired Script Component, but couldn't find any good documentation on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I have a combination of **Conditional Split**, **Sort**, and **Aggregation** that left me with one row/column. And all i needed was to assign that one row dynamically to a global variable.

1. Step 1 was to create a blank global variable, in my case a string.
2. Set source, filters and destination
   [image]
3. Edit... the Script Component
4. *Script Tab*: select your variable as the **ReadWriteVariable**.
5. *Input Columns Tab*: Check the column you want to save as variable
6. Click the **Edit Script...** button
7. Declare a temporary variable within the **ScriptMain** class
8. Assign the row return to that variable under **Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)**
9. Set your global variable to the temp variable.
   [image]
10. Save and close the second window.

Your row should now be save to the variable and can be used within any other step throughout the entire project.